# What is a hitless upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

Ive been reading software architecture in practice and I have encountered the term hitless in-service software upgrade on chapter 5 page 92.
What does a hitless upgrade means in the context of faults, failures and the recovery from there?
Maybe my less understanding stem from not being a native english speaker.
I have googled for an answer and did not find one.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term seems to be used for network hardware such as routers and switches, and means that the firmware can be upgrade without any downtime, dropped packets or connections, or ports being unresponsive.

There's even a patent for it: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090279549A1/en

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the term comes from the English idiom "to take a hit", which means roughly "to be negatively impacted". "Hitless" then means "without taking a hit".

*Hitless upgrade* thus means "upgrade without any degradation of service or performance". For a hypothetical scenario, imagine you are playing a video game and want to upgrade your graphics card at the same time. A *hitless upgrade* would be if you managed to do that without ever interrupting the game or even reducing the frame rate.

This is typically done by exploiting redundancy (at least temporary). You either already have two services running for redundancy anyway, or you temporarily start a second one. You upgrade one of them, seamlessly switch over, then upgrade the other. A real-world example: most devices that have two power supplies are actually designed to run with only one. So, you can upgrade the power supplies by pulling out PSU #1 and replacing it, then pull out PSU #2 and replacing it, without ever having to turn the equipment off.